# Some hostel booking sites we might not all know about

Tags: discussion

This isn't really a question, just some stuff I found, it is partly a plug too though since one site was built by my former employer, and through it I found out about the other sites.

- [hostelsclub](http://www.hostelsclub.com) **Book hostels with HostelsClub - The best hostels in the world - Quick, easy, confirmed booking - You only pay 10% in advance**
- [gomio.com](http://www.gomio.com/) **Hostels around the globe, no Booking Fee**
- [hostelzoo](http://hostelzoo.com/) **Hostelzoo is the world’s largest marketplace for hostels.
  We offer a free search and comparison service to our customers allowing them to book the right hostel at the best price.**

Full disclosure: My old boss made hostelzoo and asked me to check it out. I did and it looks pretty nifty. Its main feature is that you can compare the features checklists visually for multiple hostels in one location.

Hostelzoo is apparently parnered with hostelworld and hostelbookers, which most of us already know. But it is also partnered with gomio and hostelsclub, which I had never heard of before.

Anyway if you're interested check them out, it's good to know what resources are out there.

Comment: [bnbstar.com](http://bnbstar.com). I've worked for them during freelance period.

Comment: It ain't spam. I have no affiliation with any of them and don't care if you use them or not. In fact I'm sure they're in competition with each other. I just found out about them and decided to share them. Half a decade ago.