# Who wants to be the Travel Stack Exchange blogger?

Tags: discussion, beta, blog

Today on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) a few of us plugged travel related websites made by us, by people we know, or that we just found.

I had already made [a beta post to mention a few sites](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/some-hostel-booking-sites-we-might-not-all-know-about) but we realized the best place to talk about such things would be in a Stack Exchange Blog.

Several sites already have a blog and it seems you don't have to wait to get out of beta to start blogging, all you need is to have somebody eager to do the blog.

So blogging isn't my thing, I'm willing to contribute to it but not to "own" it.

Who among you think you have what it takes to be our site's blogger?

Comment: The SE community managers created some guidelines on community blogs a little while ago, which might be helpful: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: One other thing to note: it's better to have multiple contributors since it's so much work to maintain a blog with regularly updated content. The more people sharing that task, the easier it will be for everyone. So you should look for **bloggers**, not **blogger**. :)

Comment: I will gladly help as I can. I'm quite busy but I'll be happy to assist when asked.

Comment: From my experience with several other SE-blogs I highly recommend find several users that preferably even show commitment by writing a draft post (use Google Docs or something). As Laura said: its *really* hard to maintain a blog without sufficient bloggers

Answer (score 5):

I'm happy to to try and run a few posts, with input from others.  What excites me is those questions that we want to ask but are really more of a discussion type thing ("How many countries have you been to?") could actually become part of the comments on a related blog post.  We could include some quizzes in each one to get people answering and commenting.

Of course, I have no idea how one sets it up on here.  @Dori? @joel-spolsky?

Comment: It would be @RebeccaChernoff. I'll let her know this conversation is happening here, but if the community decides it's time to launch a blog, someone can pop over to the community blogs chatroom to get in touch with her: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs

Comment: It's awesome that you want to do our blog I think!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little old now, but when the time comes for a blog to be made I would love to be a contributor. I have a lot of ideas for things I'd like to write about, and like Mark, I'm really excited about the prospect of being able to actually discuss things with other travel.se members.

I think some "interviews" with our top ranked members could be really interesting too. I can't be the only one wondering how hippietrail manages to fund and organise his seemingly perpetual travelling.

Comment: Organize? Fund? Anyone seen my wallet around here? d-;