# Does Travel SE Have Its Own Blog Site?

Tags: feature-request, blog

I was wondering if Travel SE has it own blog site in common with other SE sites, as I recognise various people on here are well seasoned travellers and are always on the move ?

Comment: not yet -  see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog

Comment: For SE guidelines on blogging: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: Maybe time to revist the idea of a travel blog?

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't have a blog at the moment.

We've had this discussion earlier:

- [Who wants to be the Travel Stack Exchange blogger?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/433/108)
- [How to submit ideas for our “coming soon” blog?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/438/108)

I think it boiled down to not enough people being interested / not knowing what we could talk about.

Comment: In terms of what to talk about: summation of the place visited etc

Comment: Maybe in the future :)